# How to locate the element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

This is basically a button it will be displayed only if an option is selected from drop down. I am not able to locate using xpath

```
<td align="center" id="patientstatus" style="width:84px;">
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="StatusSubmit('212','Attended','2017-08-15')" class="btn active">
</td>
```

Comment: <td align="center" id="patientstatus" style="width:84px;"><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="StatusSubmit('212','Attended','2017-08-15')" class="btn active"></td>

Comment: Why you dont select option and then see to button's XPath?

Comment: Share your code

Comment: <td align="center" id="patientstatus" style="width:84px;">
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="StatusSubmit('212','Attended','2017-08-15')" class="btn active">
</td>

Comment: using xpath - unable to find the element

Comment: can you share your xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement to locate this element

```
driver.findElement(By.id("patientstatus"));
```

Lemme know this is helpful for you or not??

Comment: No there is two buttons with the same id patientstatus , Save & Cancel , so with id it will not work.                                                              
  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (1049.800048828125, 0.0666656494140625). Other element would receive the click: <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>

Comment: .//*[@id='patientstatus']/input

Comment: Try this
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Save']"));
 or u can check "http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html" link...

Comment: Sorry facing the following error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (1086.066650390625, 18.066665649414062). Other element would receive the click: <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
Command duration or timeout: 83 milliseconds

Comment: ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Save']")));

Answer (score 0):

If you take closer look you will observe the button is having an `<input>` tag, hence we will construct an unique `xpath` to identify the `Save` button as:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Save']"));
```

Comment: Thank you soo much after giving implicit wait , it worked , it took time to show the button after selecting from drop down ,  can you pls teme the concept of defining the xpath on our own

Comment: @Ahlad To know more about `xpath` you can refer this [**`webpage`**](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html).